# Is it possible to simplify the following expression by defining a global operator?

Tags: pstricks

The following MWE is the simplified version of the real scenario. I want to simplify `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{B} A.x B.x add A.y B.y add)` to `(!A B AddNode)`. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pstVerb
{
    % convert nodes A B to a new node C where C.x=A.x+B.x and C.y=A.y+B.y
    /AddNode {} bind def
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](6,6)
    \pnode(0,3){A}
    \pnode(4,0){B}
    \pnode(!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{B} A.x B.x add A.y B.y add){C}
    %\pnode(!A B AddNode){C}
    \psline{->}(A)(B)(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the answer is no.  The `(! )` construction introduces literal postscript, and in your suggested syntax `A` is inserted on to the stack unquoted, so you risk this already being defined as e.g. a variable with another value or a function trying to operate on something.

`pst-node.tex`, used by `pstricks` for defining and maniulating nodes, stores node names in the dictionary `tx@NodeDict`, with e.g. node `A` stored in `/N@A`.  If you are prepared to work hard you could write postscript code that would take the string `(A)` and extract the coordinates via `GetCenter`, enabling to have syntax like `(!(A) (B) AddNode)`.  However, it is unclear to me when this could win over just defining a LaTeX command

```
\newcommand{\pnodeadd}[3]{\pnode(!\psGetNodeCenter{#1}\psGetNodeCenter{#2} 
  #1.x #2.x add #1.y #2.y add){#3}}
```

and simply using

```
\pnodeadd{A}{B}{C}
```

The `pst-node` code does all its interfacing to postscript in this sort of way, using tex to build the names `N@A` etc. before postscript ever sees them.

Comment: In general: nodes are saved on PS side the reason why it is possible!

Comment: Indeed, as I say they are stored in the PS side in `tx@NodeDict` as `/N@A` etc.  The problem is the requested syntax, without quoting of the tex version of the node names.

Comment: `\pnode(! /A /B AddNode){C}` would be easy to realize